# Intervalometer for Nikon D3000

Tags: nikon, timelapse, intervalometer, nikon-d3000

I have a wireless control for my shutter release, and it works great. An intervalometer or really any device that will release the shutter at stated intervals seems hard to find for the D3000. A guy posted a YouTube video of one he crafted, but he didn't provide any instructions for doing so.

Does anyone have any ideas for what I can do other than stand and click the button over and over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're crafty, you can make something that uses your computer's serial port (or get a USB adapter for a missing port).

There are lots of instructions around the web.  This website goes into great detail:
http://www.beskeen.com/projects/dslr_serial/dslr_serial.shtml

Stark Labs offers a software-based intervalometer that can control these USB/Serial cables:
http://www.stark-labs.com/page26/DSLR_Shutter.html

It's free software, too.

Of course, you have to use a computer to do these things.

Comment: If you are familiar with Arduino programming this can be done as a simple project. Not easier, but much more portable, and can be made with much better battery life and weatherproofing than a laptop.

Answer (score 3):

By googling around the web I stumbled upon [DIY Photo Bits' Camera Control](http://www.diyphotobits.com/download-diyphotobitscom-camera-control/). From version 3.0 and upwards it supports a time lapse feature.

According to the [compatibility list](http://www.diyphotobits.com/2008/12/10/what-works-and-doesnt-work/) the D3000 should work with this software on Windows 7 and Vista.

Comment: That's what I found too, and actually, it works great! Thanks!