# I too have a time-lapse problem . . .

Tags: software-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Intervalometer for Nikon D3000](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23440/intervalometer-for-nikon-d3000)

I am an artist | Serigrapher, I am putting together a media production where one sees a serigraph created from inception to completion. I call the production Anatomy of a Serigraph. I have a Nikon d3000. I want to set it up wherein it take a frame every 5 mins. [Not much happens in ten second intervaks]. So what software do I buy? 
P>S> I'm also getting use of a video camera. I'm using Photodex -ProShow Producer to stick the program segments together.

Thank You
Rein Whitt-Pritchette
Artist Serigrapgher
rein.wpstudio@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one of these? [Remote timers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003Y2YTEE)?